# How to serialize nested classes on generic functions in wcf web service to use in REST?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf, rest

I am trying to reach our web service methods as REST (json) service. I made some configurations on web.config and I added the attribute to the functions of web service like in below.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Echo")]
ResultSet<EchoObj> GetEcho(string sth);
```

It also has an implementation like this:

```
public ResultSet<EchoObj> GetEcho(string sth)
{
     ResultSet<EchoObj> obj = new ResultSet<EchoObj>();
     obj = DoSomeWork();
     if(obj.IsOk)
     {
          obj.Item = new EchoObj();
          obj.Item.Sound = "My Sound";
          obj.Item.Volume = Volume.High;
     } else 
     {
          obj.ErrorDesc = "Sound not found.";
     }
     return obj;
}
```

Here, if the obj has error it returns the response correctly. If the obj is okay, than it does not turn any response. I am sure that, it caused due to serialization error.

The ResultSet and EchoObj classes are in below:

ResultSet class:

```
[DataContract(Name = "ResultSet")]
public class ResultSet<T> where T : class
{
    [DataMember()]
    public bool IsOk{ get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string ErrorDesc { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public T Item { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

EchoObj class:

```
[DataContract]
public class EchoObj : WaveObj
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Sound { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Volume { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime TimeAt { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public override string Code
    {
        get { return "TestSound"; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public override string Type
    {
        get { return "Test"; }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I forgot the derived class WaveObj, it looks like in below:

```
[DataContract]
public class WaveObj
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I think, something wrong on WaveObj and EchoObj but I could not find.

Are there any ideas how to fix that serialization error?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched on the books to understand what is the problem here and I aware that, wcf does not understand DateTime property to serialize it as json with only DataMember attribute. The attribute should be like in below:

```
[DataContract]
public class EchoObj : WaveObj
{
     [DataMember]
     public string Sound { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public string Volume { get; set; }

     [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
     public DateTime TimeAt { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public override string Code
     {
         get { return "TestSound"; }
     }

     [DataMember]
     public override string Type
     {
         get { return "Test"; }
     }
}
```

The attribute on DateTime property should be `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]` to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into 'KnownType' attribute 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/darrylru/archive/2011/05/04/datacontract-serialization-with-generics-amp-read-only-properties.aspx

Comment: I know KnownType attribute but it does not work, I tried before.